# Conditional calculation when using group by

Tags: mysql

I have 3 tables order, orderitem,shipment. I have to get the count of all these  and MRP of items
here is the below query

```
    SELECT
  DATE_FORMAT(order.orderdate,"%Y-%m%-%d") AS i_orderdt,
  COUNT(DISTINCT order.orderid) AS i_orderscount,
  COUNT(DISTINCT orderitem.orderitemid) as i_orderitemcount,
  COUNT(DISTINCT shipment.shipmentid) AS i_shipmentcount,
  ROUND(SUM(ifnull(orderitem.unitprice,0) * orderitem.quantity),0) AS i_mrp,
FROM order
    LEFT JOIN shipment
        ON shipment.orderid = order.orderid 
    JOIN orderitem
        ON orderitem.orderid = order.orderid

    WHERE order.orderdate >= "2014-01-01 00:00:00" AND order.orderdate <= "2014-03-31 23:59:59" )  GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(`order`.`orderdate`,"%y-%m%-%d")
```

but MRP comes wrong as order to shipment will be 1 to many relationship. How can i write a query so that the calculation happens only for distinct orderitemid ??

Comment: Can you provide the sample date set and your expected resultset

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to move the shipment count  into a subquery:

```
SELECT
  DATE_FORMAT(order.orderdate,"%Y-%m%-%d") AS i_orderdt,
  COUNT(DISTINCT order.orderid) AS i_orderscount,
  COUNT(DISTINCT orderitem.orderitemid) as i_orderitemcount,
  COALESCE(
  (
    SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT shipmentid) 
    FROM shipment 
    WHERE shipment.orderid = order.orderid 
  ), 0) AS i_shipmentcount,
  ROUND(SUM(ifnull(orderitem.unitprice,0) * orderitem.quantity),0) AS i_mrp,
FROM order
JOIN orderitem ON orderitem.orderid = order.orderid
WHERE order.orderdate >= "2014-01-01 00:00:00" 
AND order.orderdate <= "2014-03-31 23:59:59" ) 
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(order.orderdate,"%y-%m%-%d");
```

Comment: but order to orderitem is also 1 to many relationship. So if 1 order has multiple items, then i will be running same subquery multiple times for same orderid

Comment: Yes, you will. Or you *may*. It's up to the dbms to recognize that situation and find the optimal execution plan. This is nothing you should be worried about. If, however, you run into performance problems, then you would have to think of an alternative select statement.

Comment: - but this number of shipments i need for a particular day, if i take per order then i need to sum up and if i sum up i will get wrong count

Comment: I don't get it. Above statement gets you all orders with all their items. It also gets you the shipment count per order. Yes this may get executed several times, depending on how the dbms handles that, but you get this per order (and hence for that order date). So you get the same shipment count for items of the same order of course. What's wrong about this?